# Regression testing on Apple WebObjetcs GUI

Tags: user-interface, testing, regression-testing

I have recently started a new job in a company that depends heavily in an application developed with Apple Web Objects.
It happens that this company does not have a way to make automated tests whenever a new update is received, weather with bug fixes or new features.
We have no access to the code since it is a proprietary application.
My idea is to develop a suite of test cases to allow us to do regression testing through the GUI.
I have looked for tools for this, but could not find anything capable of "seeing" which components are in the GUI.

Before I arrived to the company, other people had already tried with HP LoadRunner with no success. I tried with AutoIt 3.0 just to check if it would recognize the fields, but also without success.

Anyone with experience testing such kind of application?
Which tools do you think that could fit for this purpose?

I appreciate your opinion.

Thank you!
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a few good solutions for such problem. I came down to two solutions. Both of them are image based "which means it can "see" the user interface, just as the human eye does".

**Proprietary solution**
http://www.testplant.com/

**Open source solution**
httpp://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli

Hope this can help others in the future.